# When using monkeypatch in Pytest to pass different arguments to the same function or API call, I am observing different responses

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, testcase

I'm currently working with Pytest and I need to understand how to use the monkeypatch feature to mock a function that includes an API call. Specifically, I want to obtain different responses for the function based on varying inputs within a for loop.

Eg:

```
value_1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
value_2 = {'key11': 'value11', 'key22': 'value22' 'key33': 'value33'}

class MockResponse:

    @staticmethod
    def json():
        return load_data("total_res.json")

class GetEntities:
    

   def mock_res(*args, **kwargs):
      return MockResponse().json()

   monkeypatch.setattr(api_funct, "get_data", mock_res)
   
   #test-function which have api call.
```

Above eg: always send same json file **total_res** but i need to get different response like value_1 and value_2 based on my different inputs.

Basically mock_res should send with different json file.

Tried below - Not works:

```
    class MockResponse:
    
        @staticmethod
        def json(data_entry = "total_res.json"):
            if data_entry == "total_res.json":
                return load_data("total_res.json")
            elif data_entry == "value_1":
                return value_1
            elif data_entry == "value_2":
                return value_2
            else:
                print("There is no such data!")
                return None
    
    class GetEntities:
        
    
       def mock_res(data_entry):
          return MockResponse().json(data_entry)
       data_entry = # Type of response to get

       monkeypatch.setattr(api_funct, "get_data", mock_res(data_entry))
       
       #test-function which have api call.
```

Comment: A `unittest.mock.Mock` can do that with `side effect`.

Comment: Can you brief the solution with example, please @KlausD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an input argument for the `json()` static function:

```py
def json(data_entry = "total_res.json"):
        if data_entry == "total_res.json":
            return load_data("total_res.json")
        elif data_entry == "value_1":
            return value_1
        elif data_entry == "value_2":
            return value_2
        else:
            print("There is no such data!")
            return None
```

Comment: OKay, but how/where i need to pass arug in class MockResponse and monkeypatch.setattr(api_funct, "get_data", mock_res) which json(input_date) knows and decide the return file...    @Behdad Abdollahi Moghadam

Comment: Would you please explain what does monkeypatch object do in this code? Do you have the code for it?

Comment: In api_funct.py file, get_data function have externalapi connection which send different response based on payload. while pytest, i don;t need to wait long time to get response, so i like to use monkeypatch for that. but here issue is how to get different response based on some variable or input. i gone throught the monkeypatch document but can't find the solution. @Behdad Abdollahi Moghadam